# Calculating the probability that survey responses are arbitrary

Tags: survey

I have a set of 200 responses to a Yes/No survey question: 160 Yes; 40 No. Any number of the responses (between 0 and 200) could be honest and truthful, and the rest will be arbitrary. Is there any way to calculate the probability that all the No responses are arbitrary? Does the question even make sense?

I'm not asking for the solution here - just some pointers. I have an inkling that chi-squared will be involved somehow, but (a) my expected value for No is 0, and (b) I have no expected value for Yes. I can't get my head round it.

---

**EDIT**

The above was my attempt at simplification. Here's the real situation.

The research question is about the relationship between people's judgements about reasons and the way sentences about reasons are phrased. In the study, 600 participants were presented with the same short scenario and then asked one of three questions, 200 participants per question. Here are the questions, followed by the responses in italics:

- Has he any reason to do it? *Yes: 64, No: 136*
- Is there any reason for him to do it? *Yes: 127, No: 73*
- Is there any reason why he should do it? *Yes: 156, No: 44*

What I'm trying to understand is whether there's any way to assess the amount of noise caused by arbitrary selections of 'Yes' and 'No'.

Comment: From the described data alone this is not identifiable. Some background information may or may not help. If you assume the probability that a single answer is "arbitrary" to be known, this can be computed. You could also make the prior assumption that each number between 0 and 200 is equally likely as number of truthful responses. In reality it may be hard to defend these assumptions though.

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you mean by "my expected value for No is 0"? On what information is this based? Would you be willing to *assume* this, and if not, what use can be made of it?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

On "my expected value for No is 0", I was thinking of a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test, where 0 is the number of (honest and truthful) No responses that my theory predicts. Yes, I really am as muddled about this as I look.

Comment: I don't see what a chi squared test is doing there; you don't describe this as a testing problem. An expectation of 0 is only possible if 0 is the only possibility that can occur, and would not be compatible with anything else. If you *knew* that it's zero, obviously you *knew* that all 40 Nos are not honest, but the way you ask the question, there's really not enough knowledge. I mean, you ask somebody a question and they say "no" - no way to say this is dishonest without knowing further facts. And these need to be other facts than what other people say.

Comment: What is your overall goal here? The question says "are ALL the no questions arbitrary?" Do you want to calculate a probability that every single one of the 40 No responses aren't authentic? How are you defining "arbitrary"? The people are responding randomly, or they are responding willfully incorrectly?

Comment: I have a feeling I've shot myself in the foot by trying to simplify matters for the sake of discussion. The actual situation is as follows.

Comment: I'm looking at the relationship between people's judgements about reasons and the way sentences about reasons are phrased. In my study, 600 participants were presented with the same short scenario and then asked one of three questions, 200 participants per question. Here are the questions, followed by the responses in brackets:

Has he any reason to do it? (Yes: 64, No: 136)
Is there any reason for him to do it? (Yes: 127, No: 73)
Is there any reason why he should do it? (Yes: 156, No: 44)

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is whether there's any way to assess the amount of noise caused by arbitrary (i.e. random) selections of 'Yes' and 'No' (e.g. by participants who are lazy or don't understand the question).

Comment: If you add to your question, edit the question rather than bury information in the comments.

Comment: Even those who don't understand the question or don't think it through properly will not normally answer completely random but will respond to something roughly related to the question, which complicates matters even more, because a 50/50 model for them won't be appropriate, but there's no information to build a better one. Honestly I don't think there is a way unless you have other data or information that tells you something verifiable about the persons' tendency to not answer properly.

Comment: So I suppose what I need is a way of asking each participant the same question repeatedly while erasing their memory of their previous responses. What I have at the moment is a single instant per participant.